# NullPointerException at conversion of String array to Int array

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner in programming and decided to make my own binary to decimal converter program for the fun of it. In my program, I move the String array's content to the Int array. the problem is that I seem to keep getting a `NullPointerException` error at the code where I change the String to Int. I have read the error and tried a lot of different methods to get rid of that error, but nothing helps. What could I be doing wrong?

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

My code:

```
int ans = 0;
int multi = 0;
strArray = null;
intArray = null;
if (rbBin.isSelected()) {
    txaNew.setText("");
    String num = ftxfOld.getText();
    strArray = num.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        try {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]); //I GET THE ERROR HERE
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < num.length() + 1; j++) {
        multi = intArray[j] * 2 ^ j;
        ans = ans + multi;
    }
}
txaNew.append(Integer.toString(ans));
```

Comment: how `strArray` looks before parsing?

Comment: I think you need to make sure that the `num` value is formatted like this `[1,2,3]` and also could you print out the `strArray` value after you splitter the `num` variable?

Comment: Well, it looks like I found one of my problems. the number was not split into strArray. It was only placed into it, so it only has one spot and contains the entire number. Really did not think about testing that first :'( Thanks Sasha and kucing. Is there any way to split a normal number like "100" into an array like [1,0,0]? Or should I open another question for that? (I am new here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in java you have to initialize a variabile before using it.
In your case when you do it:

```
intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]); //I GET THE ERROR HERE
```

the `initArray` is null.

Change your code:

```
strArray = num.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");

if (strArray != null){
   //You have to initialize your variable
   intArray = new int[strArray.length];

   for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
     try {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
     } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
          nfe.printStackTrace();
     }; 
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the check for `strArray != null` is necessary here, because `String#split` won't return `null`.

Comment: indeed, I think it should be `if(strArray.length > 0)`

Comment: @Vinze Even that is not necessary, because that array will always contain at least one element (the whole source string, if no split was applied).

Comment: @Vinze No worries, that happens sometimes :).

Comment: @Vinze It is not important if the strArray is empty. In any case the for cycle will not give an npe.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it, but seems like num does not split into strArray like I want it to. It only inserts the entire num value into one spot in strArray. I want num to be split like for instance "num = 100" so strArray will be [1,0,0].

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate intArray first.

```
intArray = new int[strArray.length];
```

So you will have:

```
String num = ftxfOld.getText();
strArray = num.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");
intArray = new int[strArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
try {
  intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]); //I GET THE ERROR HERE
 } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}; 
}
```